# Apple music playlist gone empty after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: music, catalina, playlist

After upgrading to catalina, all Apple music playlists are empty like the below screenshot. I have to right-click the item and choose "Show in Apple Music" to make it display songs like before.

I tried re-login and sync. Does not help. Anyone has similar issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. I had to manually sync my Library:

On the top menu bar click

> Music -> Preferences -> Check the Sync Library Button