# All my Apple Music playlists are empty

Tags: itunes, music, apple-music, music.app

Yes, this looks like a duplicate of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373044/apple-music-playlist-gone-empty-after-upgrading-to-catalina) question, but the former one was asked 4 years ago so maybe things have changed since then. At some point, all my Apple Music playlists on all devices turned empty. So the playlists are all still there, just all their contents have been deleted. Trying to bring them back on at least my iMac, where I'm currently running Ventura 13.5.2. I tried turn off and then on `Music -> Preferences -> Sync Library`. Any other suggestions? Really feeling a loss here. Thanks.

Comment: Sync with what/whom